# How do I get a standard list of US holidays for use with pcal?

Tags: command-line, calendar, postscript

I've been using the `pcal` command for ages, I use it to print out blank monthly calendars, which serve as my event diaries. I learned that it has the ability to print calendars with Federal holidays and so forth already labeled, but I can't find a list of important days to put in my `~/.calendar` file. Where do other pcal users get their holiday data?

---

Update: There are lists of holidays for various countries in the source package; it just turned out that these were not installed anywhere in the distribution I use (Arch).

Comment: Could you rework this to something shorter?

Comment: What is your distro? at least in Ubuntu the `pcal` package provides a gzipped `calendar_us.txt` (among others) in `/usr/share/doc/pcal/examples/`

Comment: Thanks. I updated the text to make it shorter and indicate that the file I was looking for is in the source package.